Finding the shortest path between two points on a sphere without crossing a parallel
I'm trying to solve a spherical trigonometry problem:

The positions of $A$ and $B$ are respectively:   Lat.
$39^\circ20'S$, Long. $110^\circ10'E$ and Lat. $44^\circ30'S$, Long.
$46^\circ20'W$  Show that if a ship steams from $A$ to $B$ by the
shortest possible route without crossing the parallel of $62^\circ S$,
the distance steamed is $5847.6$ nautical miles

Normally, calculating the shortest path between two points on the surface of a sphere is easy with the cosine formula. However, I couldn't find a way to approach this problem. Can you help?
This question is from W.M. Smart's Textbook on Spherical Astronomy, Spherical Trigonometry, Exercise 7

This is called a composite track. It consists of a great circle track from A to V1 on the limiting latitude of 62°S, then a track along the 62°S parallel to V2, and finally a great circle from V2 to B. The great circle arcs are tangential to the 62°S parallel, so they cut the meridans at 90° at those points, i.e., V1 & V2 are vertices of the great circle arcs.

The polar triangle APV1 has a right angle at V1, and you know the distances AP & V1P (the colatitudes of A & V1), so you can find the angle at P & hence the longitude of V1.

@PM2Ring I see how the path needs to be constructed, but can you give me more details on how to calculate $AV_1$ and $BV_2$?

Do you know Napier's rules for right spherical triangles?

Yes, but I don't see why the arcs cut the meridians at $90^\circ$

A vertex of a great circle is the point where it passes closest to a pole. To minimize the composite track, $V_1$ & $V_2$ need to be vertices. The great circle is tangential to the parallel of latitude at the vertex. And the meridian always cuts a parallel of latitude at 90°.
